# What metric unit does the force field use?

Tags: physics, units, force-fields

What unit does the blender physics 'Force Field' use, e.g: The 'Strength' in 'Force' ? I'm using the metric(The answer doesn't have to include only metric) preset.

Comment: Does there have to be a unit?

Comment: the "Strength" value for a Force Field is measured in Newtons (N). This is a metric unit of force

Answer (score 1):

Experimentally, with "1 meter" presets, it seems that a constant point force of strength 25 "force units" (or perhaps a tiny bit less - for some reason, 24.9 units seem to first win and later lose over gravity) corresponds roughly to 1 N, as it *approximately* compensates a 1 m/s² gravity acting on a 1 kg default cube. However, I am unaware of any (even non-SI) unit that equals about 0.04 N